# how to return a cursor along with new variable added to each row?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, callable-statement

I want to call a procedure from java.

```
Example:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE helloworld
AS
cursor data_test is
     with required_data as( select * 
      from EMPLOYEES) select * from required_data rd join DEPARTMENTS d on d.department_id=rd.DEPARTMENT_ID ;
emp_rec data_test%ROWTYPE;
more_detail varchar2(50);
BEGIN
  open data_test; 
   LOOP
         FETCH data_test INTO emp_rec;
         exit when data_test%NOTFOUND;
      more_detail =BLA.GET_MORE_DATA(data_test.empid);// Lets say the fuction return varchar2 I've total of 4  similar fields to be added in total
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Now how do I return all ***the data in the cursor(data_test ) along with more_detail*** in each row?? i.e I want my ResultSet in java to have all the values from the select statement as well as the value of more_detail.Also will my helloworld have out parameter as SYS_REFCURSOR or something else?? and when calling from java all I've to do is create a callable statement and register out parameter as Cursor to use this?

Comment: There are examples in the manual showing how to return result sets via JDBC. Besides, after your stored procedure ends the result set will be positioned after the last row, so it's practically useles. May be what you want is call `GET_MORE_DATA()` in the cursor's `SELECT` list.

Comment: @mustaccio can you point me to the reference example. and also I search about calling function from cursor but the function takes empId as an Input parameter and some values from department as well moreover how will I add it in a row?

Comment: @mustaccio what I was thinking is that along with the cursor as output parameter I can also send an associative array with key as my empid and value as whatever I get from GET_MORE_DATA. Now how retrieve these values in java using JDBC? should I make a new question out of this or what?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a `PROCEDURE` for this? Based on what's shown now, you could probably do the same thing in a  single `SELECT` which you call with `Statement.executeQuery()` and then handle the results in Java as you want.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes. I've to. :(

Comment: @MickMnemonic I resolved the issue thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for bearing with me. I've a question how can I pass an associative array without it being a pain. If I don't know the expected result?
 If you see below
public void registerIndexTableOutParameter   (int paramIndex, int maxLen, int elemSqlType, int elemMaxLen). the max length of the array to be returned needs to be known.the problem is even if I want 3 records of empID 101,102,103. I get a map of size 103. so tomorrow if want the record100001 employee. I get an error stating expected length is low.My code will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when I look at it today, How could I ask this question. This so wrong.
I didn't have much understanding of PLSQL then and asked the question without reading much. Anyway, there are many ways to solve it as I mentioned in the comment one can send back an associative array but that is a pain on the java side if you don't know the number of expected result. or one can create a nested array with an user with defined object something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE keyvalue AS object (col Number(10), col2 VARCHAR2(30));
CREATE OR replace TYPE map IS TABLE OF keyvalue ;
```

hear's how I did it. You cannot add a column to cursor but you can create you  own custom defined data type.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dbObject AS OBJECT
    (
       empId NUMBER (6),// here add as many fields you want to return or want your object to have
       emailId VARCHAR2 (25),
       hiredate DATE
    );
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE datalist IS TABLE OF DBOBJECT;

PROCEDURE get_emp_data (list OUT datalist)
   AS
      CURSOR emp_cursor
      IS
         SELECT employee_id AS empId,
                EMPLOYEES.EMAIL AS emailId,
                EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE AS hiring
           FROM EMPLOYEES;
           c_datatype emp_cursor%rowtype;

   BEGIN
  OPEN emp_cursor();
      list := datalist();
      LOOP
        fetch emp_cursor into c_datatype;
         EXIT WHEN emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
         list.extend;
         list(emp_cursor%ROWCOUNT):=DBOBJECT(c_datatype.empId,c_datatype.emailId,c_datatype.hiring);         
      END LOOP;
   END get_emp_data;
```

Now you want to call this from java: here is the code:

```
String dataTypeName = "DBOBJECT";
        String dataTypeListName = "datalist";
        StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(dataTypeName.toUpperCase(), connection);      
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();
        CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call TEST_PACKAGE.get_emp_data(?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, dataTypeListName.toUpperCase());      
        cs.execute();
        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array)cs.getObject(1)).getArray();
        for(Object tmp : data) {
            Struct row = (Struct) tmp;
            int index = 1;
            for(Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {               
                System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(index) + " : " + attribute);                                          
                ++index ;
            }

        }
        cs.close();
```